# split div into 2 columns

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to split a div into 2 columns. I tried to find the answer in another question but i still don't get it.
I succeeded to split the div into 2 columns but now the content of the div is very far from each other (and i want them to be close).
here is my html:

```
<div id="connect_us" class="container">
<h1>תאמו איתנו פגישה עוד היום</h1>
<div id="right">
<form action="connect">
    <input type="text" name="name" value="שם"><P>
    <input type="text" name="company" value="שם חברה" onclick="clear()"><P>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="טלפון" onclick="clear()"><P>
    <input type="text" name="mail" value="דואר אלקטרוני" onclick="clear()"><P>
    <input type="text" name="message" value="הודעה" onclick="clear()"><P>
</form>
</div>

<div id="left">
<input type="text" name="company" value="kt zufr" onclick="clear()"><P>
</div>
</div>
```

here is my css:

```
#connect_us{
text-align: center;
font-family:"open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular",arial,"Times New Roman";
color:gray;
overflow:auto; 
width: 100%; 

}
#left, #right { 
  width: 45%; 
  margin:5px; 
  padding: 1em; 

   } 

#left  { float:left;  }
#right { float:right; }
```

what i am trying to do is like this(as u can see the 2 colums are close):[image: example]

Comment: You can use div {
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;
} to reduce gap.

Comment: you can try max-width in px to avoid using full space.. like this...   http://jsfiddle.net/tdv8rs1m/

Comment: The issue is that you are floating in a full screen width div -> #connect_us{width:100%} so the 2 divs are going to float to the far sides of the screen, hence the big gap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sol 1:** 
Try to specify max-width for `#contact_us` div like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tdv8rs1m/1/)**:

```
#connect_us {
    text-align: center;
    font-family:"open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular", arial, "Times New Roman";
    color:gray;
    overflow:auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

or

**Sol 2:**  you can float both right and left divs to left side as you are using full screen.. So you can use this to avoid space between 2 div's:

```
#left, #right  {
    float:left;
    background-color:#ddd;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#left, #right { 
 width: 45%; 
 margin:5px; 
 padding: 1em; 
 display:inline-block
}
```

display:inline-block will help you to fix your problem

```css
#Left,#Right
{
width:45%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #c4c4c4;
height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="Left">
    I am left
    </div>
  <div id="Right">
     I am Right
    </div>
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is simple enough as you think.

```
<div class="left">
.....
</div>

<div class="right">
.....
</div>

.left, .right {
 float: left;
 width: 48%;
 margin : 1%;
 padding : 1%;
}

#connect_us {
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
}
```

This will work and your 2 div will be much closer. If you are also using border then i must suggest you to use ***box-sizing: border-box*** property on the divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:table-cell;` for both columns and `display:table` for the main wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem. Problem is you are not specifying the width of input fields... Look, div has no visible proportion initially and we are not putting any background-color or border to define it. So visible things are our form fields (The INPUT BOX). So define it like...

```
#left input,
#right input{
    width:100%;
}
```